# SQL query to find last day of current month?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
 LastDay_CurrentMonth
```

Hi everyone I have a query to find the last day of current month, which is surely working well, but I am unable to understand it, because I have other similar requirements and have to change it accordingly.

Can somebody explain it to me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of this query you don't understand?

Comment: See [Tibor Karaszi's ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes: Getting rid of the time portion](http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_datetime.asp#GettingRidOfTimePortion): "The dateadd/datediff version can easily be varied to get the start of the current month, quarter or year..."

Comment: The sample you showed is flawed in two ways. (1) What is the use of the *last second* on the last day of the month? If SMALLDATETIME it will round up anyway; if DATETIME or DATETIME2 you will lose some data that happened in that last second. Always better to use >= this month and < next month. In addition to Tibor's great article, please see https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries (2) just pedantic, but SPELL OUT `SECOND` and `MONTH` instead of using `s`, `mm`, and `m`... makes the code *much* more self-documenting.

Comment: Thanx @Arvo you can have a look in below comment.

Comment: Thanx @Onedaywhen that is a good stuff.......

Comment: @AaronBertrand - There are so many answers to the last day question on the internet. How do we know which one is correct and is the shortest ?

Comment: @MasterJoe I don't know how to answer that question. Which way to display a date or accept a string is correct? What exactly do you need to do with the last day? Why does "shortest" factor into quality?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Get the DateTime of *Now*

```
GETDATE() -- 2011-09-15 13:45:00.923
```

Calculate the difference in month's from '1900-01-01'

```
DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) -- 1340
```

Add the difference to '1900-01-01' plus one extra month

```
DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0) -- 2011-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

Remove one second

```
DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0)) -- 2011-09-30 23:59:59.000
```

Comment: +1 for great explanation - in [SQL Server "Denali", it will be much simpler](http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/08/sql-server-denali-new-function-to-get.html): `SELECT EOMONTH (GETDATE());` :-)

Comment: @marc_s but an important distinction is that `EOMONTH` will return the last day at midnight. Folks think this will make their reporting queries magical but I think many will be surprised when they're missing a full day of data (assuming a time component) if they use `BETWEEN` and/or don't adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: ah, okay - interesting information - thanks! Is there going to be a `EODAY()` function as well?? :-)

Comment: No, I fought to eradicate `EOMONTH` and instead implement `BOMONTH`, `BODAY`, etc. I also thought `MONTHEND`, `MONTHSTART` etc. would make a lot more sense than abbreviations. I lost. The current logic makes no sense. What good is the last day at midnight? My reporting queries want the whole month. I'd rather calculate beginning of month, then run >= that and < that + 1 month. Now, no matter what the data type is, I'm not going to lose or double-count anything. I feel an additional blog post warning of the dangers and uselessness of `EOMONTH` coming on...

Comment: Hi @Mikael Eriksson that was ofcourse a good explanation but in the line:                                                            DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0)                          or simply                                         DATEADD(M,1341,0)                                               what I am actually trying to do.

Comment: @Ajendra - You are adding 1341 months to the date '1900-01-01'. Try this `select cast(cast('1900-01-01' as datetime) as int)`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Is it better to convert this into a function ?

Comment: @MasterJoe No, you should use [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - thanks, but what if its not supported by the SQL server version ?

Comment: @MasterJoe Then you are using a version of SQL Server that is not supported.
You could do an inline table valued function. For performance reasons you should stay away from scalar UDFs.
Some work has been done in SQL Server 2019 to adress the issue with scalar UDFs. [Scalar UDF Inlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the last day of current month but ignores time

select EOMONTH(GETDATE())

[From Microsoft tech net](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx)

Comment: EOMONTH() does not work for SQL Server 2008. It is a new feature of SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION  EOMONTH
(
    @date datetime,
    @months int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
     declare @eom datetime
     declare @d datetime
     set @d = dateadd(MONTH, @months, @date)
     select @eom =   dateadd(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,datediff(MONTH,0,@d)+1,0))
    RETURN  @eom 

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT` `DATEPART` `(DD,EOMONTH(GETDATE()))` AS 'the last day of the Current month'

- Here `DATEPART` function is used to print the integer part of day.. if the the name of day is asked then we have to use `DATENAME()` function.
- In query, last day means end of the month so we used `EOMONTH()` function.
- `GETDATE()` is to represent current month.