# Average daily count for every month

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I need to write a stored procedure to generate a report. In this report, I need to show the average daily count for the check amount and check count. Here's what I have for now:

```
SELECT  SendingBank,
        CheckCount As TotalCount,
        CheckAmt As TotalAmt,
        AVG(CheckCount/30) AS AvgDailyCount,
        AVG(CheckAmt/30) AS AvgDailyAmt
FROM tblRptT001 
WHERE InwardClearingDate = @asInwardClearingDt
GROUP BY InwardClearingDate, SendingBank, CheckCount, CheckAmt
ORDER BY InwardClearingDate
```

I know what I did for the average count is totally wrong and I am stuck with that as not every month have the same number of days. I tested this sp and it works, except not the way I wanted for both the average field.

Any ideas on how I should approach this? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit**: This is the sample data

```
InwardClearingDate  SendingBank     CheckCount  CheckAmt
2014-03-03          ABC Bank        1800        70000.00
2014-03-21          BBC Bank        526         456090.00
```

and result that I wanted

```
Sending Bank|Total Count| Total Amt| Daily Avg Count| Daily Avg Amt
ABC Bank    | 1800      | 70000.00 | 60             |2333.00
```

The parameter is the Inward clearing date, for example `2014-03-03`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired output.

Comment: that's not sample `data` it does look like the `expected result` though. For example, where is "InwardClearingDate, ChequeCount, ChequeAmt" in the sample?

Comment: opps sorry. I'll edit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see whether this is what you are looking for,

```
Declare @asInwardClearingDt Date
Declare @month int = (Datediff(Day,@asInwardClearingDt,Dateadd(Month,1,@asInwardClearingDt)))

Select  SendingBank,
        Sum(CheckCount) As TotalCount,
        Sum(CheckAmt) As TotalAmt,
        Sum(CheckCount)/@month As AvgDailyCount,
        Sum(CheckAmt)/@month As AvgDailyAmt
From    tblRptT001
Where   Datepart(MONTH,InwardClearingDate) = Datepart(MONTH,@asInwardClearingDt)
And     Datepart(MONTH,InwardClearingDate) = Datepart(MONTH,@asInwardClearingDt)
Group By SendingBank
```

nf91, Please comment

Comment: Declare @month int =  Datediff(Day,EOMONTH(@asInwardClearingDt,-1),EOMONTH(@asInwardClearingDt))
One another way for the number of days.

Answer (score 2):

> > I know what I did for the average count is totally wrong and I am stuck with that as not every month have the same number of days.

To address that, consider applying DAY and EOMONTH() functions on InwardClearingDate

```
SELECT SendingBank, CheckCount As TotalCount, CheckAmt As TotalAmt,
    AVG(CheckCount/DAY(EOMONTH(InwardClearingDate)) AS DaysInMonth) AS AvgDailyCount,   
    AVG(CheckAmt/DAY(EOMONTH(InwardClearingDate)) AS DaysInMonth) AS AvgDailyAmt
FROM tblRptT001 
WHERE InwardClearingDate = @asInwardClearingDt
    GROUP BY InwardClearingDate, SendingBank, ChequeCount, ChequeAmt
    ORDER BY InwardClearingDate
```

Comment: I can't seem to use the EOMONTH() functions. Is is because I am using SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Yes, that's an SQL Server 2012 function. What it does is get the last day of a calendar month. However, there is a workaround in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429885/sql-query-to-find-last-day-of-current-month

Comment: thank you for the explanation and idea! I will try to work around this.  I also found this function which is quite helpful SELECT CONVERT(DATE, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, current_timestamp)+1,-1)); not exactly it but it gives me some idea and makes me understand more. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this

```
SELECT S.SendingBank,
       S.TotalCount,
       S.TotalAmt,
       AVG(T.CheckCount) AS AvgDailyCount, 
       AVG(T.CheckAmt) AS AvgDailyAmt
FROM
(
  SELECT SendingBank, CheckCount As TotalCount, CheckAmt As TotalAmt
  FROM tblRptT001 
  WHERE InwardClearingDate = @asInwardClearingDt 
  GROUP BY InwardClearingDate, SendingBank, CheckCount, CheckAmt  
) S JOIN tblRptT001 T ON S.SendingBank = T.SendingBank
GROUP BY S.SendingBank,S.TotalCount,S.TotalAmt,T.InwardClearingDate
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42f98/1)**