# First and last day of this month last year

Tags: sql-server

I'm declaring some months and dates and need help on getting the first and last date of this month last year.

So far I have the following.

```
DECLARE @today date Set @today = cast (getdate() as date)
DECLARE @firstdaylastmonth date Set @firstdaylastmonth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @today)-1, 0)
DECLARE @lastdaylastmonth date SET @lastdaylastmonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@today),0))
DECLARE @lastdaythismonth date SEt @lastdaythismonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@today)+1,0)) 

-- DECLARE @firstdaythismonthlastyear SET 
-- DECLARE @lastdaythismonthlastyear SET


Select 
@today,
@firstdaylastmonth,
@lastdaylastmonth,
@lastdaythismonth

-- @firstdaythismonthlastyear
-- @lastdaythismonthlastyear
```

But am having trouble finding the last 2 declarations.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Didn't you try just googling instead of asking question?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri is Stack Overflow here for decoration?

Comment: I am pretty sure that stack has a lot of answers on this question already. 2 seconds in google and you will get plenty of answers

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - well, if you can find an exact dupe, vote to close this question as a dupe.

Comment: @Jamiec, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429885/sql-query-to-find-last-day-of-current-month   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437362/how-to-get-first-and-last-date-of-current-year

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EOMONTH ( start_date [, month_to_add ] )` Function For SQL Server 2012 and above.

Comment: Great! The code using this function will look like:
`DECLARE @firstdaythismonthlastyear date SET @firstdaythismonthlastyear = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()), -1))
DECLARE @lastdaythismonthlastyear date SET @lastdaythismonthlastyear = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
SELECT @firstdaythismonthlastyear, @lastdaythismonthlastyear`

Answer (score 0):

This does what you asked for

```
DECLARE @firstdaythismonthlastyear date 
SET @firstdaythismonthlastyear = DATEADD(year,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @today), 0))
DECLARE @lastdaythismonthlastyear date 
SET @lastdaythismonthlastyear = DATEADD(year,-1,@lastdaythismonth)
```

The first builds on what you had done for `@firstdaylastmonth` and the second uses your precalculated `@lastdaythismonth`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dateadd to offset by 12 months:

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()
SELECT DATEADD(M,-12,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)),@mydate),101)) ,
'Last Day of Previous Month, Last Year'
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(M,-12,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101)) AS Date_Value,
'First Day of Current Month, Last Year' AS Date_Type
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@mydate,101) AS Date_Value, 'Today' AS Date_Type
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(M,-12,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),101)) ,
'Last Day of Current Month, Last Year'
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(M,-12,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),101)) ,
'First Day of Next Month, Last Year'
```

Comment: Why are you converting dates back and forth to `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 0):

We can `CAST` the first day of current month into a date and subtract one year for `@firstdaythismonthlastyear`, and just subtract a year from `@lastdaythismonth` to get `@lastdaythismonthlastyear`.

```
DECLARE @today date Set @today = cast (getdate() as date)
DECLARE @firstdaylastmonth date Set @firstdaylastmonth = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @today)-1, 0)
DECLARE @lastdaylastmonth date SET @lastdaylastmonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@today),0))
DECLARE @lastdaythismonth date SEt @lastdaythismonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@today)+1,0)) 

DECLARE @firstdaythismonthlastyear date SET @firstdaythismonthlastyear = DATEADD(year, -1,CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(@today),'-',MONTH(@today),'-',1) as date))
DECLARE @lastdaythismonthlastyear date SET @lastdaythismonthlastyear = DATEADD(year, -1, @lastdaythismonth)

Select 
@today,
@firstdaylastmonth,
@lastdaylastmonth,
@lastdaythismonth,
@firstdaythismonthlastyear,
@lastdaythismonthlastyear
```